# PHP Script Automatic Download new file added in FTP Server

Tags: php, ftp, download, raspberry-pi

I'm currently using a Raspberry Pi for an automatic video player

I want to ask, whether is it possible or not a PHP program that can automatically (say for each day) download new files added in FTP Server.

i.e. I have an FTP Server that contains Video Files, each day it will check if there is a new video file added and the program would download the new file automatically into some directory (my raspberry pi storage)

Currently this is the basic download script that i have for an ftp

```
<?php

// define some variables
$local_file = '/mydirectory/video.mp4';
$server_file = '/FTPdirectory/video.mp4';
$ftp_server="xx";
$ftp_user_name="xx";
$ftp_user_pass="xx";

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

ftp_pasv($conn_id, TRUE);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. You want to know if you can download from FTP with PHP and you have a script for that. So problem solved?

Comment: sorry if it's not clear, the ftp script i have only downloads specific file. I want the program to automatically download new files added in the ftp server by other person and the script would automatically download the new file added with one day interval

Answer (score 0):

Definitely! Set up a cron job to call the PHP script:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-add-jobs-to-cron-under-linux-or-unix-oses/

Alternatively you can use Kermit to automate FTP as well:

http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ftpscripts.html

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is loop through a local dir with PHP, make a list (json for easy storage) of all files and then compare that to FTP. If there's items that aren't in the local list, get them through FTP using Kermit as suggested by Jeremy Morgan.